# Differentials on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, graph-embeddings

I have been thinking about the problem of establishing a diffeomorphism between an open domain $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and the graph of a differentiable function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$, that is, the set $$G(f)=\{(x,f(x))\in\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}:x\in A\}.$$
I have thought about the idea of defining a function $F:A\to G(f)$ and prove that this function is a embedding, which will give me the desire diffeomorfism between $A$ and the image of $F(A)=G(f)$. Calculating the Jacobian of $F$ it can be confirmed that F is differentiable in the classical way but the problem is that for the embedding I need to see that the differential of $F$, that is $dF_p$, is injective but I don't know how to calculate it.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can explicitly write down what $F$ is and find its inverse.

Comment: If you have calculated the Jacobian, you should include the result into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\pi: G(f) \to A$ the projection, where $G(f) = A \times f(A).$

We have $\pi \circ F = Id.$

If $dF(p).v = 0$ then
$$ v = Id(v) = d(\pi \circ F)(p).v = d\pi(F(p)) \circ dF(p).v = 0.$$

Thus $dF(p)$ is injective.

Comment: ohh ingenious way of doing it but how do you get that $Id(v)=d(\pi \circ F)(p).\, v$? Do you mean $d(Id(p)).\, v$?

Comment: Since $d(Id(p))$ is linear, then $d(Id(p)) = Id.$